# Have a job executed only if a specific number of executors is available on an agent

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-agent

I have a Jenkins controller and an agent with two executors.

I have a multijob (A) that executes some jobs including one multijob (a). My multijob (a) must run on the slave (1) with two executors. So when it runs, it means I have only one executor available (which is what I want). But if an other multijob (B) is triggered with the multijob (b) and need to run on the slave (1), I want to be sure that it will start only if the other multijob (a) is finished.

Is there a way to implement that under Jenkins Multijobs?

[image]